# Custom Android Components with XML children

Tags: android

I'm an iOS developer that is relatively new with Android and I'm trying to create reusable components that separate the controller logic and View definition.  I want a pattern similar to iOS IBOutlets where you define a class that can be used with different xib files or storyboard layouts.

For example, say I want to create a custom progress bar component.  I want the user to be able to provide the required children and design and style them separately in xml.

Here's some pseudo code of what I'm trying to accomplish:

layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout>
    <!-- A vertical progress bar -->
    <CustomProgressBar>
        <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView id="@+id/bar" src="@drawable/bar_image" />
            <TextView id="@+id/label" text="Bar 1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </CustomProgressBar>

    <!-- A horizontal bar using same controller class -->
    <CustomProgressBar>
        <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView src="@drawable/background_image" />
            <ImageView id="@+id/bar" src="@drawable/bar_image" />
            <TextView id="@+id/label" text="Bar 1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </CustomProgressBar>
<FrameLayout>
```

Then my custom class might look like:

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends FrameLayout {
    private ImageView bar;
    private TextView label;
    .
    .

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        // Store the references of the components
        bar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bar);
        label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);

        // Now I should be able to write general code for this component
        // using the reference components I found
    }
}
```

In the above example, the developer is instantiating 2 CustomProgressBars in the same xml file.  But each bar's layout is drastically different (child display tree and orientation is different).  The obvious problem here is that the xml won't compile because I'm using the same ids for different views in the xml.  To fix the compilation issue, I could change the id names, but then the controller class won't know how to find references to those children.

Is there another way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are methods in `ViewGroup` called `getChildCount` and `getChildAt` which will allow you to pull the child views by index.

So what you will have to do is something like:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    getProgressViews(this);
}

private ImageView bar;
private TextView label;

private void getProgressViews(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);

        if (view.getClass().getSuperclass() == ViewGroup.class) {
            getProgressViews((ViewGroup) view);
        }
        if (view instanceof ImageView) {
            bar = (ImageView) view;
        }
        if (view instanceof TextView) {
            label = (TextView) view;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are looking to use these to also manually draw them to screen you need to override the `onLayout` method.

Comment: This doesn't work out because if you look at the second example I posted, the component doesn't know how to differentiate between the two ImageViews.  The example above would assume the last ImageView is that bar, which may not be true for all UI designs.

Comment: Yes, but you can set a background and an image on an ImageView, you shouldn't have to use two different ImageViews for that. Also if you really want to do it with two of them, you can easily just add a content description and differentiate them that way.

Comment: That makes sense, but I guess the desire is that is that I should be able to
have any type of layout and any combination of children in any order and have the component still work.  I'm not sure what a content description is, so I'll look into that.